# Unity 3d: Passar a informação de uma cena para outra

Tags: unity3d, ui

Prezado(a),
Eu fiz uma pesquisa para encontrar solução de problema que não consegui encontrar em outra fonte encontrada no google.
A ideia é quando um usuário preenche a informação em um cena identificada como cena1 que conter objeto UI, como o caso de tela de autenticação de acesso e entre todas as coisas. Ao efetuar o click do botão, passar para outra cena como cena2 contendo a informação exibida que foi preenchida em uma cena1. Por exemplo: digitei em campo de texto "João" e quando eu clico em botão confirmar que vai passar para cena2. E na cena2 exibe João em um rótulo ou label. tem algumas funções genéricas que faz isso?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando a função:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Nome", variavelNome);
```

Para Salvar na cena 1, e então na cena 2 utilize:

```
PlayerPrefs.GetString("Nome");
```

Para manipular a informação!

Comment: Na Cena1, eu coloco uma variável como playernome que é atribuído com campo texto que foi preenchido, por exemplo: playernome = txtnome.tex.trim(); PlayerPrefs.SetString("Nome", playernome);. Para colocar no label seria desta forma: lblnome.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Nome")? Eu farei um teste, e darei um retorno de teste.

Comment: Isso assim mesmo!

Answer (score 2):

É possível utilizar uma classe estática para a persistência dos dados ao longo das cenas. Você pode declarar uma classe *UserData*, por exemplo, e utilizar propriedades estáticas para armazenar estes dados, por exemplo:

```c#
class UserData{
    // Nome de usuário do jogador.
    public static string userName = "";

    // Password do jogador.
    public static string password = "";
}
```

Não é necessário herdar *MonoBehaviour* nesse caso, nem anexar o *script* a um objeto (aliás não herdando *MonoBehaviour* nem será possível anexá-lo).

Desta forma, na Cena1 provavelmente você já tenha um *script* com um método que será executado ao clicar do botão que realiza a troca para a Cena2. Antes de realizar o carregamento da Cena2 você pode armazenar suas informações, por exemplo:

```c#
public void TrocaDeCena(){
    // Armazena os dados do usuário.
    UserData.userName = campoDeTextoUsername.text; // Aqui você já deve ter a referência do campo de texto onde o usuário digitou.
    UserData.password = campoDeTextoPassword.text; // Aqui você já deve ter a referência do campo de texto onde o usuário digitou.

    // Carrega a Cena2.
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Cena2");
}
```

Para recuperar os dados guardados na classe estática, na cena seguinte no método *Start* de algum *script* anexado ao elemento UI que exibirá as informações você terá um código parecido com o a seguir:

```c#
public void Start(){
    // Aqui você já deve ter a referência do elemento text que exibirá o dado.
    // Exibe o nome do usuário armazenado.
    labelUserName.text = UserData.userName;
}
```

Esta é uma das formas mais simples de trafegar/persistir dados entre cenas. A forma de como obter os valores do campo de texto e como atribuir os valores nas *labels* pode mudar de acordo com a sua versão do *Unity* mas a abordagem utilizando classe estática funciona desde versões bem antigas.

Answer (score 1):

Arthur,

para solucionar esse problema você pode usar um objeto vazio com um script de `GameController` para guardar as informações da primeira cena. Com o script criado basta apenas adicionar o método [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) para que assim ao realizar o load para a cena2, você ainda tenha o objeto `GameController` ativo na cena. Adicionando o design patterns singleton, você pode consultar os metodos da classe de qualquer script, sem precisar ter a referencia em cena.

Ex: `GameController.Instance.GravarNome("teste");`

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string nome = "";

    private static GameController instance = null;
    public static GameController Instance { get { return instance; } }

    void Start()
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }

    public void GravarNome(string nome)
    {         
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public string ConsultarNome(){
        return this.nome;
    }
}
```